# mssql execution order guarantee when conversion in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have following scalar function

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getOM
    (   @mskey INT,
        @category VARCHAR(2)
    )
RETURNS VARCHAR(11)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @om VARCHAR(11)
    SELECT @om = o.aValue
    FROM dbo.idmv_value_basic o WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE o.MSKEY = @mskey and o.AttrName = 'OM'
        AND EXISTS (
            SELECT NULL
            FROM sys.sequences s WITH (NOLOCK)
            WHERE CONVERT(INT, replace(o.aValue, '1690', '')) BETWEEN s.minimum_value AND s.maximum_value AND s.name = concat('om_', @category)
        )   
    RETURN @om  
END
```

Problem with that is, that o.aValue could not only have numeric values, so that the convertion can fail, if it is executet on other rows of **idmv_value_basic**, where *attrName* is **not** 'OM'.

For some unknown reason this morning, our MSSQL-Server changed the execution order of the where conditions and the convertion failed.

How could I define the selection, so that is guaranteed, that only the the selected lines of **idmv_value_basic** are used for the selection on *sys.sequences*?

I know, for SQL the execution order is not deterministic, but there must be a way, to guarantee, that the conversion would not fail.

Any ideas, how I could change the function or am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

By the way, when I execute the selection manualy, it does not fail, but when I execute the funtion it fails.

We could repair the function while changing something, save and then change it back and save again.

Comment: You could use `TRY_CONVERT` instead

Comment: Use `case` statement around `convert()` function (and `try_convert()` is always better choice).

Comment: thanks, for that, it do the trick. But why the answers only as Comment? I could not mark the question es solved.

Comment: For starters, try to stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: Also this would be much more efficient as an inline table-valued function than a scalar.

Comment: @AaronBertrand what you mean exactly?

Comment: I mean exactly that you have a function that has to be called for every row, which can represent a lot of overhead. A function that is written slightly differently (so that the logic can be folded in or "inlined" into the query that references it) is often much more efficient. See [this article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4772/refactor-sql-server-scalar-udf-to-inline-tvf-to-improve-performance/?utm_source=AaronBertrand), for example.

Comment: Ah ok, now I understand. Yes this function is only called once per select or it is called for onyl one row per select.
Creating a scalar function was more a decision of maintenance an the simplicity of calling functions instead of a stored procedure.

Comment: "Yes this function is only called once per select or it is called for onyl one row per select" - you sure about that? Show how you call it....

Comment: I call it from a Process of our Framework with "select getOM($mskey, $category)". This process is only called for one mskey at once. So when it is called for more then one entry, the process is separetly called per entry and so function is only called once per entry.

Will writing this, it sounds strange, but this was the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try answer the question: "Any way to guarantee execution-order?"

You can - to some extent. When you write an EXISTS, what sqlserver will actually do behind the scenes is a join. (check the execution plan)

Now, the way joins are evaluated depends on cardinalities. Say you're joining tables A and B, with a predicate on both. SQL Server will prefer to start with the table producing the fewest rows.

In your case, SQL Server probably decided that a full scan of sys.sequences produces fewer rows than dbo.idmv_value_basic (WHERE o.MSKEY = @mskey and o.AttrName = 'OM') - maybe because the number of rows in idmv_value_basic increased recently?

You could help things by making an index on dbo.idmv_value_basic (MSKEY, AttrName) INCLUDE (aValue). I assume the predicate produces exactly one row pr. MSKey - or at least not very many - and an index would help SQL Server choose the "right way", by giving it more accurate estimates of how many rows that part of the join produces.

```
CREATE INDEX IDVM_VALUE_BASIC_MSKEY_ATTRNAME_VALUE 
    ON dbo.idmv_value_basic (MSKey, AttrName) INCLUDE (aValue);
```

Rewriting an EXISTS as a JOIN can be done, but requires a bit of finesse. With a JOIN, you can specify which kind (Loop, Merge or Hash) and thus force SQL Server to acknowledge your knowing better and forcing the order of evaluation, ie.

```
SELECT ...
FROM dbo.idmv_value_basic o
INNER LOOP JOIN (SELECT name 
           FROM sys.sequences 
           WHERE (..between min and max) 
          ) AS B 
       ON (B.name= concat('om_',@category ))
WHERE o.MSKey=@mskey AND o.AttrName = 'OM'
```

And lose the WITH (NOLOCK)